# JGit PullCommand Exception

Tags: jgit

We are using git to maintain our source. URL like git@xx.xx.xx.xx:XYZ.git. I'm using JGit to pull the changes.

```java
UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider user = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("xxxx", "xxxx");
localPath = "E:\\murugan\\Test\\GIT_LOCALDEPY";
Git git = new Git(localRepo);
PullCommand pcmd = git.pull();
pcmd.setCredentialsProvider(user);
pcmd.call();
```

I'm getting the following exception when I execute the code.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://git@xx.xx.xx.xx:22: 
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$StringType:Passphrase for C:\Users\Murugan.SOLVER\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

If username/password security is not an issue, you can specify the credentials as part of the connection in the .git/config file of the local Git repo:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://<user>:<pwd>@<host>:22/<remote-path-to-repo>/
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure your SSH parameters on your machine before using Git. Here is a link, from github, for configuring it.

https://help.github.com/categories/56/articles

especially this one: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

This will help you set up everything properly (you should adapt everything, since you are probably not connecting to GitHub)

Comment: hi.. we already add the ssh parameter and we are using tortoise git  to push and source from git server. But Here i'm trying to use Jgit to do the push and pull actions.

Comment: ok, then I don't know. Search about the passphrase. Because the log seems pretty clear : there is something wrong with your passphrase. You should take a look at the mentioned file : C:\Users\Murugan.SOLVER.ssh\id_rsa